# Fine Uploader S3 - Nowhere to safely call the asynchronous "setUploadSuccessParams()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I've been digging into Fine Uploader S3 for 2 weeks now, overall this is a really good plugin.

However, I found one issue which I still haven't been able to overcome.  I'm not sure if this is a plugin limitation or plain stupidity from my end.

I need to use this method.  This is a method where I can set some custom parameters to shoot over to my server after a successful upload to Amazon S3:

```
var params = {
    file_storage: 's3',
    file_module: 'gallery',
    file_path: $gallery_upload.fineUploaderS3('getKey', id),
    file_name: name,
    file_type: $gallery_upload.fineUploader('getFile', id).type
};

$gallery_upload.fineUploader('setUploadSuccessParams', params, id);
```

There are 2 problems:

(1) This is asynchronous, and runs completely on a separate thread as the actual algorithm that fires out the "success" message.

(2) Depending on different places, the "getKey" method returns undefined.  This is understandable, but I want the "one place" that getKey() will ALWAYS return that evil key I got from S3.

===========================================================

So ends up that I've got nowhere to place my snippet.  I've tried a few places:

(A) Submitted callback

```
.on('submitted', function(event, id, name){
```

Nope.  As expected, the getKey is not ready yet.

---

(B) "statusChange" callback @ newStatus == "upload successful".

```
.on('statusChange', function(event, id, oldStatus, newStatus){
```

This works sometimes, and sometimes not.  Due to asynchronous issue.  Also, quite hacky.  Looks like this.

```
.on('statusChange', function(event, id, oldStatus, newStatus){
    console.log('Event: statusChange', oldStatus, newStatus);

    if( newStatus === 'upload successful' )
    {
        var params = {
            file_storage: 's3',
            file_module: 'gallery',
            file_path: $gallery_upload.fineUploaderS3('getKey', id),
            file_name: name,
            file_type: $gallery_upload.fineUploader('getFile', id).type
        };
    }

})
```

---

(C) Progress callback only @ "uploadedBytes == totalBytes"

```
.on('progress', function(event, id, name, uploadedBytes, totalBytes){
```

ONLY WHEN uploadedBytes == totalBytes.  But again, this sounds dangerous due to the asyncrhonous thing.  It's also quite hacky.

---

(D) Progress callback

```
.on('progress', function(event, id, name, uploadedBytes, totalBytes){
```

This seems to work the best, but, it sounds extremely hacky.  It's spamming the setUploadSuccessParams() so it's really bad!  I was wondering if there is a "correct way" to do this.  For example, some bang-on event that works immediately.

Comment: Why do you need to pass the key in two different forms to your upload success endpoint?  Fine Uploader will include that as a param by default.  It also includes the file name.

Comment: Hello Ray,  thanks for your quick comments as always.  I'd actually like to manipulate the key on client side.  This is just an example.  I'll break it up into pieces by JS and send it over to the server.

Comment: Ah, so you'd like to send a modified version of the key as a param with the upload success POST?

Comment: Yes that's correct.  I'll keep the native key parameter, but add a few extra parameters (which are bits and chunks of the native key) for the server

Comment: Interesting situation.  I think the best (and only) way to handle this is by overriding the key option with a promissory function.  I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, your code that generates the params for the upload success call is NOT async, correct?

Comment: Hi Ray, correct.  It's not async.  Just standard line-by-line code to manipulate from the original key.

Comment: Ok, I've put together an answer that seems to address your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key of each file is determined as late as possible, currently just before the upload occurs.  This happens after the `onUpload` event callback handler is executed (not that it matters since onUpload does not allow for a promissory return type).

So, the best course of action to handle your unique situation would be to override the `objectProperties.key` option.  The function, when invoked, would generate a key name, and use that to set your upload success params for this file.

For example:

```
objectProperties: {
    key: function(id) {
        var name = this.getName(id),
            key = this.getUuid(id) + '.' + qq.getExtension(name),
            params = {
                file_storage: 's3',
                file_module: 'gallery',
                file_path: key,
                file_name: name,
                file_type: this.getFile(id).type
            };

        this.setUploadSuccessParams(params, id);

        return key;
    }
};
```

Note: not tested, but conceptually correct.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!  Although the key was not grabbed off the S3 after the upload finishes, I guess that should be sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: The key you specify will be the exact key used when the file is sent to s3.